# Substitution on Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The technique of substitution is a prevalent one in mathematics. It can be used in so many branches spanning from algebra to calculus.

I appear to run into a problem, however, when trying to use substitutions on series, or at least my use of substitution is fruitless.

Consider:
$$\sum_{x=1}^{n} f(x) = g(n)$$

Now let $x=y^2+k$ as a random substitution. My issue is that now the limits of the sum are from $y^2+k=1$ to $n$ rather than the generally more useful $y=1$ to $n$.

So what I am asking is this essentially; is there a mechanism of using substitutions to transform a sum into something more manageable, akin to how substitutions are used in other areas of maths.

A extension (somewhat) is something like this:
Given 
$$\sum_{x=1}^{n} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{k^2+k+1}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{n}{n+2}\right)$$

Can we show that
$$\sum_{x=1}^{n} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{k^2-k+1}\right) = \arctan(n)\,?$$

With a substitution, I tried $k=-x$ but I ran into a problem with limits.
I know that this particular problem can be solved using telescoping series.

Comment: I think there's discrepancies between $x$ and $k$, it's sort of not clear what is being summed here.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(k-1)^2+(k-1)+1 = k^2-k+1$, you need to substitute $k' = k-1$ into the 2nd sum:

The 1st sum has bounds $1 \le k \le n$, i.e. $0 \le k-1 \le n$, so the 2nd sum has bounds $0 \le k' \le n-1$. Using this substitution, we have:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\arctan\dfrac{1}{k^2-k+1} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\arctan\dfrac{1}{(k-1)^2+(k-1)+1} = \sum_{k' = 0}^{n-1}\arctan\dfrac{1}{k'^2-k'+1}$

$= \arctan 1 + \displaystyle\sum_{k' = 1}^{n-1}\arctan\dfrac{1}{k'^2+k'+1}$ $= \arctan 1 + \arctan\dfrac{(n-1)}{(n-1)+2}$

where in the last step, we used the given summation for $n-1$ instead of $n$. This should be easy to simplify using the tangent addition formula.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple. As an aside, can you give a hint for of a substitution (if possible) to get from the sum of $r$ to the sum of $r^2$ and the sum of that to $r^3$? Again, I have proved the general formula's using the difference between cubics and quartics tell respectively but was just looking for another method.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the dummy variable in a summation, you have to change the limits to make sure you get the same terms.  It is the same as substitution in integrals.  In your first example of $x=y^2+k$ you did not define which of $y,k$ is the new summation variable.  If it is $k$, the range becomes $1-y^2$ to $n-y^2$  If $y$ is the new summation variable, it is even harder because of the $y^2$.  If that doesn't please you, it is not a good substitution to make.

Comment: For clarity's sake I meant summing $y$. Does that mean you would advise against the strategy of substitution for determining series when said substitution is not linear? My inspiration for the question came from the observation that for integrals you can use a remarkable range of substitutions. Because of the parallels between summation and integrals I was inquiring to find out if more complex substitutions were possible. It seems like that would not be case.

Comment: It looks like that substitution would not help.  To get increments of $1$ in $x$ you need increments of $1$ in $y^2+k$, which means the values of $y$ that you want are not simple.  The idea of substitution is to simplify things.  It is conceivable that there is some summation this would help, but it seems unlikely.